# Is there any open sourced projetct for IOT based IP camera cloud recording?

Tags: camera, cloud, iot, ip-camera, recording

I'm working on an IP camera (embedded developing), and I want to develop a cloud recording system. A camera can push recording to a cloud server, and iOS/Android can pull the recording from the server to play the video (which works in a way like Apple HomeKit IPcam cloud server, or TUYA smart cameras). Is there any open sourced project to reference? (both the camera side embedded software and the cloud server side)

Comment: That will depend on the hardware you intend to use. Software for an IP camera will be very different from a camera attached to a PC or an embedded controller. Generally, questions seeking for specific libraries are off-topic here.

Comment: It's an embedded IP camera, I got the audio and video data, as long as the project in in C/C++, I cam cross compile it(maybe modify part of it to fit into the camera), or even just take a reference of the logic, and re-code my own project.